# Error in xyplot panel

Tags: r, plot

I have defined this function:

```
fresults <- function(svrFit,testSet,var) {
  library(caret)
  if(substr(deparse(substitute(svrFit)), 1, 3)!="svr") {
  options(digits=3)
  tiff(filename = paste("Predicted vs. Residuals (Train)", "_", deparse(substitute(svrFit)), ".tiff", sep=""), 
       res = 300, height = 2480, width = 3508, compression = "lzw")
  print(xyplot(resid(svrFit) ~ predict(svrFit),
         type = c("p", "g"),
         xlab=list(label = "Predicted",cex = 2), ylab = list(label = "Residuals",cex = 2), 
         cex = 1.5, scales = list(cex = 1.5, tick.number = 8)),
         panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
         panel.abline( h=0, lty = 1, col = "gray60", lwd=5)
         })
  dev.off()
  }
}
```

But it returns this error when it should plot also a horizontal line:

```
Error in printFunction(x, ...) : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

> traceback()

```
5: printFunction(x, ...)
4: print.trellis(xyplot(resid(svrFit) ~ predict(svrFit), type = c("p", 
       "g"), xlab = list(label = "Predicted", cex = 2), ylab = list(label = "Residuals", 
       cex = 2), cex = 1.5, scales = list(cex = 1.5, tick.number = 8)), 
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.abline(h = 0, lty = 1, col = "gray60", 
               lwd = 5)
       })
3: print(xyplot(resid(svrFit) ~ predict(svrFit), type = c("p", "g"), 
       xlab = list(label = "Predicted", cex = 2), ylab = list(label = "Residuals", 
           cex = 2), cex = 1.5, scales = list(cex = 1.5, tick.number = 8)), 
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.abline(h = 0, lty = 1, col = "gray60", 
               lwd = 5)
       })
2: print(xyplot(resid(svrFit) ~ predict(svrFit), type = c("p", "g"), 
       xlab = list(label = "Predicted", cex = 2), ylab = list(label = "Residuals", 
           cex = 2), cex = 1.5, scales = list(cex = 1.5, tick.number = 8)), 
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.abline(h = 0, lty = 1, col = "gray60", 
               lwd = 5)
       }) at Surrogate.R#67
1: fresults(gbmFitRy, testSetRy, "Ry")
```

I'm certain the solution is trivial but I cannot find it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot.trellis` function (what ends up being called when you use `print`) accepts a few `panel.*` arguments so when you are passing it one named `panel`, it cannot guess which one you are trying to use. And complains. Just make sure to use the full argument name and you should be good to go. Refer to `?plot.trellis`.

Edit: rather, the fact that `panel` was passed to `print.trellis` and not `xyplot` was the sign of a syntax issue, a bad use of parenthesis. The correct syntax should be:

```
print(xyplot(resid(svrFit) ~ predict(svrFit),
      type = c("p", "g"),
      xlab =list(label = "Predicted",cex = 2),
      ylab = list(label = "Residuals",cex = 2), 
      cex = 1.5, scales = list(cex = 1.5, tick.number = 8),
      panel = function(x, y, ...) {
        panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
        panel.abline( h=0, lty = 1, col = "gray60", lwd=5)
      }))
```

Comment: flodel: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried to solve the error but I can't. I changed the code to: panel = function(...) { panel.xyplot(...) panel.abline( h=0, v = NULL, lty = 1, col.line = "gray60", lwd=5, identifier = "abline") }

Comment: The problem is the name of the argument: "panel". If you could tell me why are you passing a "panel" argument, where it is documented, then maybe I can help further.

Comment: In ?plot.trellis there's this example: `## Using seekViewport

## repeat same plot, with different polynomial fits in each panel
xyplot(Armed.Forces ~ Year, longley, index.cond = list(rep(1, 6)),
       layout = c(3, 2),
       panel = function(x, y, ...)
       {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           fm <- lm(y ~ poly(x, panel.number()))
           llines(x, predict(fm))
       })`

Comment: `xyplot`, not `plot`. These are two different functions.

Comment: Got lost here. I use xyplot and the example also.

Comment: oups. let me search a bit more. Have you tried to just remove the `print()` part? I.e. just do `xyplot()`.

Comment: If I remove plot then when I call the function from another R script nothing is printed.

Comment: Or you have a parenthesis issue: you are closing the `xyplot` call after the `scales` argument so `panel` ends up being passed to `print`, not `xyplot`.